# How to add a configuration dialog to a Confluence plugin

Tags: java, confluence

I'd like to have a configuration UI for when someone selects my plugin, to allow them to select a mode/title of the page it will create.

In much the same way the "Retrospective" option does...

[image: Retrospective-config-ui]

Can someone point me in the direction of what I need to do for this please.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to page and space blueprints. When you click on the main "Create" button, you see all the available page blueprints on the wiki. When you click on "Create Space", the space blueprints. Check the following documentation:

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-blueprints

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: I've downloaded that, unzipped and run "atlas-run". But this gives lots of errors. Mostly around "ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Class". e.g. .BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAccessor'.

Comment: I'd need the logs, but make sure you use java 8 for Confluence >= 5.8. And I'd recommend the Atlassian SDK version **6.1.0**, we have experienced problems with the latest 6.2.2

Comment: Works much better with JDK 8 and...               <confluence.version>5.9.3</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>5.9.3</confluence.data.version>
        <amps.version>6.1.2</amps.version>
        <create.content.version>4.0.9</create.content.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.0</plugin.testrunner.version>

Comment: In Confluence, the logs are in the data folder, in the logs folder -> atlassian-confluence.log. if you are using atlas-run or atlas-debug, you can output the logs to a file with 
atlas-run>debug.log
so you can open it with your text editor